# Selecting employees from departments with average salary smaller than

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have to write query that returns all employees from departments with average salary smaller than 12000.
I wrote down this query

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
HAVING AVG(SALARY) < 12000
ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC;
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Instead of taking all employees from those departments it takes only ones with salary smaller than 12000.
How to write this query properly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to calculate AVG for each department, separated from the names.

Answer (score 1):

You need the average salary for the department. I would use a window function:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM (SELECT e.*, AVG(SALARY) OVER (PARTITION BY DEPARTMENT_ID) as avg_salary_dept 
      FROM EMPLOYEES e
     ) e
WHERE avg_salary_dept < 12000
ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC;
```

Comment: Oh okay, I will read about window functions. Could you only tell me what does "e" mean? Is it some sort of variable?

Comment: e is a table alias. I highly recommend you research both table and column aliases, if you are unfamiliar with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need subquery :

```
SELECT e.DEPARTMENT_ID, e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES e
WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID IN (SELECT e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
                          FROM EMPLOYEES e1
                          GROUP BY e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
                          HAVING AVG(e1.SALARY) < 12000
                         )
ORDER BY e.LAST_NAME ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery

```
SELECT e.DEPARTMENT_ID, e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES a
WHERE exists (SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEES b
                          where a.department_id=b.department_id
                          HAVING AVG(b.SALARY) < 12000
                         );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
SELECT e.DEPARTMENT_ID, e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME
       from employee e where e.DEPARTMENT_ID in 
                                   (select e.DEPARTMENT_ID from employee e 
                                                  group by e.DEPARTMENT_ID
                                                   having avg(salary)<3000)
```

Comment: Please, explain what he did wrong and why this solution works. This will help him/her to understand what is going on and might prevent same mistake in future.